# Detect if an object is not being touched in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to figure out a way to detect if an object in Unity is not being touched. Basically, I need a true or false value on whether or not an object is being touched.

Comment: Add callbacks to the touch events and use a boolean to keep track.

Comment: Can you please show code on how to do this?

Comment: Read it all https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) and [`OnCollisionExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit.html) to build a component like

```
public class TouchDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here you store all currently touching objects
    private HashSet<GameObject> touching = new HashSet<GameObject>();

    // Here you store the actual flag whether something is currently touching
    [Header("Debugging")]
    [SerializeField] private bool isBeingTouched;

    // This property is read-only from the outside
    // When setting it it invoked the OnTouchStateChanged
    // event if the value is different to the previous one 
    public bool IsBeingTouched
    {
        get => isBeingTouched;
        private set
        {
            if(isBeingTouched == value) return;

            isBeingTouched = value;
            OnTouchStateChanged?.Invoke(isBeingTouched);
        }
    }

    // For not needing to poll the state continuously attach listeners to this
    // event in order to be notified when the state has changed
    public event Action<bool> OnTouchStateChanged;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // TODO Maybe filter for tag etc e.g.
        //if(!collision.gameObject.CompareTag("SomeTag") return;

        // Add this object to the set of current colliders
        if(!touching.Contains(collision.gameObject) touching.Add(collision.gameObject);

        // Set flag 
        IsBeingTouched = true;
    }


    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // TODO Maybe filter for tag etc e.g.
        //if(!collision.gameObject.CompareTag("SomeTag") return;

        // Remove the object from the current colliders 
        if(touching.Contains(collision.gameObject) touching.Remove(collision.gameObject);

        // Check if there are still other colliders left and update the flag
        IsBeingTouched = touching.Count > 0; 
    }
}
```

If needed you can also exchange or extend it with [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) and [`OnTriggerExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html) and the according 2D versions depending on your needs.

---

So now in another script you can either check the current state by using

```
if(!GetComponent<TouchDetector>(). IsBeingTouched)
{
    // currently Not touched
}
```

Or you can add a callback to

```
GetComponent<TouchDetector>(). OnTouchStateChanged += HandleTouchStateChanged;

...

private void HandleTouchStateChanged (bool touching)
{
    if(! touching)
    {
        // happens only once when nothing is touching the object anymore
    }
}
```